# KOMA-Script: caption, subfig, and captionlabel

Tags: formatting, captions, subfloats, koma-script

My problem is best illustrated with an example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font={sf,md,sl,small}}
\setkomafont{caption}{\itshape\sffamily}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\upshape\bfseries\sffamily}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \subfloat[Test]{\hskip70pt}\hskip30pt
 \subfloat[Test 2]{\hskip70pt}
\caption{Main caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I wish for the labels `(a)` and `(b)` to render as *(a)* and *(b)* as opposed to **(a)** and **(b)**.  How can I go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least when using a `KOMA-Script` class together with the `caption` package, you also need to redefine `labelfont` with `\captionsetup`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font={sf,md,sl,small},labelfont={sf,md,sl,small}}
\setkomafont{caption}{\itshape\sffamily}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\upshape\bfseries\sffamily}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \subfloat[Test]{\hskip70pt}\hskip30pt
 \subfloat[Test 2]{\hskip70pt}
\caption{Main caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Both `\setkomafont` do not have an effect here. It only has an effect as long as you don't overwrite the KOMA settings with `\captionsetup`.

Comment: In the example, `\setkomafont` effects the main caption.

Comment: Upps, (of course) you are right, I didn't read the `[subfigure]` part.